# Statistically significant that this is a fair coin?

Tags: probability

I was given the following question:

Given a coin (2 outcomes, $H$ heads and $T$ for tails), I flip it 8 times. The results are

$$ H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H$$

How do I know if this is statistically significant that this is a fair coin, with 95% confidence?

So my approach to the question is:

1. Find out the probability of this outcome occurring, assuming it is fair, the outcome is $0.5^8 = 0.00391$
2. Find out the possibilities of this happening in a binomial distribution
3. Test using $p$-value

However, how do I do steps 2 & 3? In other words, I know the various outcomes of this result but how do I prove with statistical significance that this is a fair coin?

Answer (score 1):

Step 2 is what you worked out in step 1

You have the p value $<5%$ so it's significant evidence that the coin is biased.

Bear in mind that this is based on just one experiment so your conclusion might be different if you repeated the experiment etc etc..